# How do I get my 'Detached HEAD' commits back into master

Tags: git, version-control

Looks like a few days ago I created a branch called `detached HEAD` and have been committing to it.  My normal process is to commit to `master` and then push that to `origin`.  But I can't push `detached HEAD`.

My next stop screwed me. I selected `git checkout master` - and my `detached HEAD` branch disappeared. Going back to my project all of my changes in the past few days have been wiped.

Is there anyway I can get those changes back?

Comment: Use git reflog to find the lost commits.

Comment: See http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: If your current "branch" is HEAD, then CREATE `tmp` branch and then switch to `master` and merge `tmp` to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/860099

Answer (score 485, accepted):

If `checkout master` was the last thing you did, then the [reflog](http://man.github.com/git/git-reflog.html) entry `HEAD@{1}` will contain your commits (otherwise use `git reflog` or `git log -p` to find them). Use `git merge HEAD@{1}` to fast forward them into master.

As noted in the comments, [Git Ready has a great article](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) on this.

`git reflog` and `git reflog --all` will give you the commit hashes of the mis-placed commits.

[image: Git Ready: Reflog, Your Safety Net]

Source: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: Not being a power git user this was helpful, but not details enough. It prompted me to search the net though - thanks. I found http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html very useful

Comment: For anyone running HEAD@{1} in Powershell (Windows), you'll get a non descriptive error like error: unknown switch 'e'.  This is because curly braces have special meaning in Powershell.  You'll want to type this instead: 'HEAD@{1}'.

Comment: If you are using fish shell, you will get this error `merge: HEAD@1 - not something we can merge`, fish removes the curly braces so switch to bash first, then it will work.

Comment: Instead of merging you can also cherry-pick the detached commits, like `git cherry-pick HEAD@{3}`. This doesn't clutter the history with lots of merges if there are several commits to rescue.

Comment: Git for Windows seems to need quotes for the `HEAD@{1}`, otherwise it comes with strange errors....`error: unknown switch `c'` ->  so use  `git merge "HEAD@{1}"`

Comment: To get back your work:
1. Run `git reflog`
2. Find the SHA of the commit e.g. `abcd123 `
3. Run `git merge abcd123 `

Answer (score 94):

If your detached HEAD is a fast forward of master and you just want the commits upstream, you can

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

to push directly, or

```
git checkout master && git merge [ref of HEAD]
```

will merge it back into your local master.

Comment: This worked for me and @Josh Lee's approach didn't. So I'm glad this worked!

Comment: That pushes the commits on the detached head back to origin (origin/master), but leaves you in a detached state locally. Is `git checkout origin master` the best way to get back on the master branch? It would seem better to merge into master first, then push back to origin.

Comment: works for me  thanks.