# How to recover commit from 'detached head state'?

Tags: git, merge

I checked out another branch with updates then made a few changes, switched back to the main git and now the changes disappeared! Can I get them back? the terminal was basically:

```
$ git commit
[detached HEAD 7c09e17] Fixed some stuff
  files changed, insertions(+), deletions(-)
$ git push master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 7c09e17... Fixed some stuff
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge theother/directory
```

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845505/gitx-how-do-i-get-my-detached-head-commits-back-into-master?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming you're still on master:

```
git merge 7c09e17
```

should be enough. `git` is usually good about telling you the commit IDs, if you watch the terminal.

Comment: checkout master, git merge 7c09e17, git checkout master, git push, seems to solve it, thanks!

Comment: and, out of curiosity, is there a way to see/cancel all these commits on my local machine?

Comment: @NoBugs, if you want to see all dangling commits (commits not on a branch), I think you want `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs`.

Comment: and if you didn't watch the terminal, you can get the info you need from git reflog

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I wish I could upvote you more than once! This just saved my butt!

Answer (score 23):

I had a *similar* problem. I found `git reflog` to be a life-saver. In case it helps illustrate it use, here's the output:

```
e3191c5 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from ec31ccf0735240d0cdc5a44fd443039c3caa43f0 to master
ec31ccf HEAD@{1}: commit: Added code and data for simulation.
781b9ee HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 3bd804e635b913840c71b7f8a33665460580d45f to 781b
3bd804e HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to 3bd804
```

My situation was a bit different in that I had made a commit while in a detached HEAD state starting from a very old commit.

If I simply wanted to merge `ec31ccf0735240d0cdc5a44fd443039c3caa43f0` (aka `ec31ccf`, which is where I *had* been) into `master`, I think `git merge ec31ccf` or `git rebase ec31ccf` might have worked. 
But this would be mostly merging ancient history in my case (with merge conflicts, etc.).

Instead, I just wanted to recover what I'd done on `ec31ccf`, and `git cherry-pick ec31ccf` worked nicely.

Comment: `git reflog` helped me alot when finding my lost detached branch ! thank's for mentioning it !