# How to recover lost commits after git submodule update and checkout?

Tags: git

This is a variant on similar questions, where commits end up in a headless branch. I am adding this question to cover this particular case. In my case, the issue is the following:

- I did a git submodule update, which left the repository in a headless state (and I forgot to checkout again to master)
- I committed code, several commits in fact
- As I was about to push to github, I realized I was in a headless state, and switched to the `master` branch (the github app makes it soooo easy)

The result: my commits were now in git limbo.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041156/how-to-recover-commit-from-detached-head-state), I found my way out using `git reflog`:

```
> git reflog
6b0da0d HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
6b0da0d HEAD@{1}: pull --rebase --progress --prune --recurse-submodules=on-demand origin: check
d55ecfb HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from fed7916169d740644dbbd9ea48e2d2cd510ce32d to master
fed7916 HEAD@{3}: commit: more secret stuff.
818bf20 HEAD@{4}: commit: incredible stuff I am doing, hopefully won't end up in limbo.
...etc...
```

The commit `fed7916` is the one I want to merge to `master`. For this, I simply typed:

```
> git merge fed7916
```

The merge went without problem (it should since it was anyway branched from where `master` was at) and all my commits were now reachable again, and ready to be pushed to github.