# Git branch no branch make data disappear

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I had this issue that the output of `git branch` used to be

```
* (no branch)
  master
```

Then I committed the changes and switched to the `master` branch, by running

```
git checkout master
```

Now I have to get back some files in `*(no branch)`. How can I do that? The application is in production and has several changes, but I can't access...

Comment: possible duplicate of [gitx How do I get my 'Detached HEAD' commits back into master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845505/gitx-how-do-i-get-my-detached-head-commits-back-into-master)

Comment: you can use git reflog to see when you switched the branch

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reflog` to see where your `HEAD` has been before. Then it's best to use

```
git checkout -b some_new_branch_name commit_hash_from_reflog
```

to create a branch from that "lost" commit. You can then normally work with that branch and e.g. merge it.