# How can I locate a previous commit made in "detached HEAD" mode?

Tags: git

For example, I did a checkout to a previous version such as 894e8b4e93d8f3. Then I make some revise in this previous version and **commit the change** but not push due to a detached HEAD error. Next, I did another checkout so the code changed to another version and the previous revision seemed to have lost. How can I find the previous committed code? Is the committed code still in local repository?

Comment: You can do `git revert`.

Comment: Do you want to erase the commit from your history? Or simply get the state of file(s) prior to that commit back

Comment: Do you see the commit in `git log --all --graph`?

Comment: I'd inspect `HEAD`'s reflog (by running `git reflog`) and attempt to identify the commit of interest by its commit message. Once you've found it, you can check it out using its hash.

Comment: I'm going to use https://stackoverflow.com/q/4845505/1256452 as the duplicate here, since it's the same entry into the problem, even though that posting is itself marked a duplicate.